# Typescript: define type with keys from other type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Suppose you have this Typescript class:

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

How would I declare an object type that has the same properties, but `any` type, but for which all properties are optional? Here are some possible values that should be compatible with that type:

```
data = {};
data = {name: 'John'};
data = {name: anyValue};
data = {age: 'can be a string'}
data = {name: anyValue, age: null};
```

I'm not even sure what to search for.  I've tried something like this:

```
let data: {(keyof Person): any};
```

But that does not compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last try is almost correct!

```js
let data: { [k in keyof Person]: any };
```

Comment: When writing complex types, I always write `let test: ReadOnly<any>;` somewhere and use "Go to Type Definition" on `ReadOnly` to get to typescript's own types library and look at the types defined there.